# example of using ajax and json to dynamically update search results in grails application

Tags: ajax, grails

I'm trying to build a search UI similar to that found on the zappos website (not for shoes though).  Shown here would be a small piece of the left nav bar where users would refine their search:

[image]

As the user checks/unchecks different options an ajax request is sent to a search controller (json) and the search controller sends back the results to the browser, and the page is updated with the new search results.

Are there any plugins or examples of something similar?  Or is it not a good idea to use ajax to update search results of the entire page.

Comment: No need for a plugin to that, just handle the `params` Map in your controller and filter your domain class using [criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

Comment: You might want to consider using a JS framework to manage the dynamic HTML "building" (from JSON data), as opposed to building the HTML with JS Strings (ugly & hard to maintain). Off the top of my head: jQuery plugin: datatables, Knockout JS, Angular JS, etc. Many of these use/suggest a standard JSON data format that you can easily produce in Grails with "as JSON".

Comment: Yes I like the idea of using params and criteria.  That's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

As your comments mention, you don't need a lot of extra stuff to build this in to Grails.  Just use the remoteLink tag you can pass in parameters to it using some simple javascript and hava a simple controller action take in the parameters and return your result as a templated view.